# Changing font size on AlertDialog returns null when trying to find the textview

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this code to create an Alert Dialog

```
 //Create Alert Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // Do something with the selection
                Toast.makeText(JourneyPlannerActivity.this, "Selected:"+item,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        alert.getWindow().getAttributes();
        //Set text Size
        TextView textView = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setTextSize(16);
```

When I try and get the textview it always returns null, any idea why? I've looked at all the solutions for changing text size on an alert dialog and it looks like it is this way, anyone see anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer : [Custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22040965/934560)

In this example , the programmer has made a custom dialog, and is changing the font of dialog title. You can use it for changing text size of your dialog message.